# Sending data from apple watch to iPhone when iphone is not nearby using Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I am using Xcode 11.3.1. I wants to make an iOS and watchOS app using swift5. I understand we need to use `WatchConnectivity` class to send and receive data using message but, my concern is that how do we send data when Apple Watch is far from iphone. Assuming it's cellular and wifi both but still i need solution to get data from apple watch to iphone.

I wants to store those collected data from apple watch to iphone's local db by using realm.

Answer (score 0):

It's only [`sendMessage(_:replyHandler:errorHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615687-sendmessage) and [`sendMessageData(_:replyHandler:errorHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615617-sendmessagedata) that require reachability, the [other methods](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession) dequeue data once Apple Watch comes within range of the paired iPhone. If you need to transfer data while the devices are out of range and can depend on a watchOS network connection, look into the [URL Loading System](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system) or [CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/cloudkit/).